# Runtime filtering on IEnumerable objects with muiltiple conditions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ienumerable

I have collection of PersonCollection of type `IEnumerable<Person>`

It contains:

- Name
- City
- District
- Country

And some more collection, say an arrays

```
Array CityList = {"Delhi","Goa",...}
Array CountryList = {"India","USA",...}
Array DistrictList = {"Acb","Xyz",...}
```

I want to apply the filter on

```
attribute City, Country & District 
of PersonCollection on the basic 
of CityList, CountryList & DistrictList.
```

Say I have a Filter

```
Array CityList = {"Delhi",}
Array CountryList = {"USA","UK"}
Array DistrictList = {null}
```

then I need a filtered result of such records having

```
City = Delhi
OR
Country = USA
OR 
Country = UK
```

---

any solution to get the required result?

Comment: What do you mean: "Any linq query which cant hit a performance...?"

Comment: Any linq querry which cant take much time, resource, etc.... optimum query to get the result.

Comment: These are in-memory objects so the linq statements will not be slower than writing your own code to do these operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PersonCollection.Where(p =>
    CityList.Contains(p.City) ||
    CountryList.Contains(p.Country) ||
    DistrictList.Contains(p.District)
)
```